# Create new column and fill with added strings from same df with underscore as delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
ds = pd.DataFrame({'place': [1,2,3], 'date': ['6/7/2021','1/1/2031','1/4/2011'], 
'city':['Moscow','New York','Sidney'], 'kids':[5,3,1]})
```

that looks like this:

```
city        date      kids   place
Moscow    6/7/2021     5       1
New York  1/1/2031     3       2
Sidney    1/4/2011     1       3
```

I need to add a new column 'key' to a DataFrame, values in which would be a string that would be a union of values in each row of certain columns: 'city', 'date', 'place' with an underscore ('_') as a delimiter.

**Eventual goal:**

```
city        date      kids   place   key
Moscow    6/7/2021     5       1     Moscow_6/7/2021_1
New York  1/1/2031     3       2     New York_1/1/2031_2
Sidney    1/4/2011     1       3     Sidney_1/4/2011_3
```

First of all, I've converted integers in a 'place' column into strings:

```
df['place'].apply(str)
```

Secondly, I've removed columns I don't need (but actually this column should be in a resulting df):

```
col_list= list(df)
col_list.remove('kids')
```

Then I've tried to create a new column and to fill it with appended strings:

```
df['key'] = df[col_list].apply(lambda x: x.sum())
```

But it returns me NaN values in a 'key' column and actually values still appended not with an undersoce as a delimiter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just add the columns similar to building a `str`, you just need to cast the last column to `str`:

```
In[87]:
df['key'] = df['city'] + '_' + df['date'] + '_' + df['place'].astype(str)
df

Out[87]: 
       city      date  kids  place                  key
0    Moscow  6/7/2021     5      1    Moscow_6/7/2021_1
1  New York  1/1/2031     3      2  New York_1/1/2031_2
2    Sidney  1/4/2011     1      3    Sidney_1/4/2011_3
```

**Timings**
With a 30k row df:

```
%timeit  df['city'] + '_' + df['date'] + '_' + df['place'].astype(str)
df
%timeit df[['city', 'date', 'place']].astype(str).apply('_'.join, 1)
%timeit df[['city', 'date', 'place']].astype(str).transform('_'.join, 1)

100 loops, best of 3: 9 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 84 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 83 ms per loop
```

This method seems to be 10x faster, probably as it's just a straight vectorised addition, `apply` is a cythonised `for` loop, it looks like `transform` needs to do some form of `grouping`, sorting, and then creating a new object with index aligned to original df which is where the time is being taken is my guess

Other @JohnGalt method:

```
%timeit pd.Series(df[['city', 'date', 'place']].astype(str).values.tolist()).str.join('_')

100 loops, best of 3: 10.5 ms per loop
```

So this is marginally slower than my answer.

Comment: 'The definition of genius is taking the complex and making it simple.'. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could make it more generic with `apply` and join

```
In [485]: ds[['city', 'date', 'place']].astype(str).apply('_'.join, 1)
Out[485]:
0      Moscow_6/7/2021_1
1    New York_1/1/2031_2
2      Sidney_1/4/2011_3
dtype: object

In [486]: ds['key'] = ds[['city', 'date', 'place']].astype(str).apply('_'.join, 1)

In [487]: ds
Out[487]:
       city      date  kids  place                  key
0    Moscow  6/7/2021     5      1    Moscow_6/7/2021_1
1  New York  1/1/2031     3      2  New York_1/1/2031_2
2    Sidney  1/4/2011     1      3    Sidney_1/4/2011_3
```

Or, to use `.str`  methods, you could

```
In [493]: pd.Series(ds[['city', 'date', 'place']].astype(str).values.tolist()).str.join('_')
Out[493]:
0      Moscow_6/7/2021_1
1    New York_1/1/2031_2
2      Sidney_1/4/2011_3
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `df.assign` with `df.transform` (v0.20+):

```
In [203]: df.assign(key=df[['city', 'date', 'place']].astype(str).transform('_'.join, 1))
Out[203]: 
       city      date  kids  place                  key
0    Moscow  6/7/2021     5      1    Moscow_6/7/2021_1
1  New York  1/1/2031     3      2  New York_1/1/2031_2
2    Sidney  1/4/2011     1      3    Sidney_1/4/2011_3
```

Note that `df.assign` is not inplace, to persist the changes, you'd do: `df = df.assign(.....)`.

Comment: Didn't know `transform` was added to dfs as a first class method +1

Comment: @EdChum Yes! As of 0.20, it has.

Comment: I should pay more attention to the what's new sections, useful to know

Answer (score 0):

apply could also do the job:

```
df[key] = df[columns].apply(lambda x: '_'.join([str(y) for y in x]))
```